# How to set correct return type for function that returns new function with last parameter optional

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a function that returns a new function that has the last parameter as optional and I don't know how to achieve correct return type.

Something along the lines of (I'm aware this does not work since `LastOptional` does not exist):

```
export function convert<T extends (...args: any[]) => void>(convertFunction: T): (...args: LastOptional<Parameters<T>>) => void {
  ...
}
```

Used like:

```
function test(first: string, second: number): void {
  if (first === 'hello') {
    console.log('bye');
  } else if (second === 4) {
    console.log(5);
  }
}

const converted = convert(test);

converted('hello');
```

Here, `converted` should have type signature:

```
const converted: (first: string, second?: number | undefined) => void
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish this with the following type:

```
export type LastOptional<T extends any[]> =
  T extends [infer T1] ? [T1?] :
  T extends [infer T1, infer T2] ? [T1, T2?] :
  T extends [infer T1, infer T2, infer T3] ? [T1, T2, T3?] :
  T extends [infer T1, infer T2, infer T3, infer T4] ? [T1, T2, T3, T4?] :
  T extends [infer T1, infer T2, infer T3, infer T4, infer T5] ? [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5?] :
  T;
```

Used like:

```
export function convert<T extends (...args: any[]) => void>(convertFunction: T): (...args: LastOptional<Parameters<T>>) => void {
  ...
}
```

However, this will not keep the parameter names, any suggestions on how to keep those are welcome.